# Error parsing xml when using javax.xml library

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse a test xml in order to delete one node. This is my code

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
documentBuilderFactory.setIgnoringComments(true);
documentBuilderFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(file);
```

This is the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Company>
<Name>My Company</Name>
    <Executive type="CEO">
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
        <FirstName>Jim</FirstName>
        <street>123 Main Street</street>
        <city>Mytown</city>
        <state>NY</state>
        <zip>11234</zip>
    </Executive>
</Company>
```

When I inspect the object "document" I see some strange things. For example:

fNodeValue:

```
[null, null, 
, null, My Company, 
, null, CEO, 
    , null, Smith, 
    , null, Jim, 
    , null, 123 Main Street, 
    , null, Mytown, 
    , null, NY, 
    , null, 11234, 
, 
, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,     null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl$RefCount@52914505]
```

It seems that it does the parsing wrong. If I try to get children nodes I can't get anything.

Any solution to this?

Comment: Hi @mannuk can you please specify what the error is?in your xml you forget to close thee <Company> tag but I parsed the file without any problem even if you see all this null value. I can get any node and do anything with the nodes, so I don't understand the problem.

Comment: @Mario Sorry It was a mistake during the paste. I can't see errors or anything